# Springboard crash app

Tags: ios

Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d

Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, scene-update watchdog transgression: life.favor exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 10.00 seconds |  | ProcessVisibility: Foreground | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-update | WatchdogVisibility: Foreground | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 130.940 (user 130.940, system 0.000), 88% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 107.214, 72% CPU" | )
    Triggered by Thread:  0

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185868980 -[__NSSetM removeObject:] + 4 (NSSetM.m:252)
1   Foundation                      0x00000001864ac938 _rowCrossIndexNoteBodyVariableWasRemovedFromRow + 196 (NSISEngine.m:278)
2   Foundation                      0x00000001862dce50 expression_merge + 688 (NSISLinearExpression.m:404)
3   Foundation                      0x00000001864ae6bc _substituteOutAllOccurencesOfBodyVar + 732 (NSISEngine.m:553)
4   Foundation                      0x00000001864ad85c _pivotToMakeBodyVarNewHeadOfRowWithHead + 436 (NSISEngine.m:618)
5   Foundation                      0x00000001864aea78 _minimizeConstantInObjectiveRowWithHead + 148 (NSISEngine.m:1071)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001862e1684 -[NSISEngine tryUsingArtificialVariableToAddConstraintWithMarker:rowBody:usingInfeasibilityHandlingBehavior:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 380   (NSISEngine.m:1667)
7   Foundation                      0x00000001862ddef0 -[NSISEngine tryToAddConstraintWithMarker:expression:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 552 (NSISEngine.m:2468)
8   Foundation                      0x00000001862ddb80 -[NSLayoutConstraint _addLoweredExpression:toEngine:integralizationAdjustment:lastLoweredConstantWasRounded:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 284 (NSLayoutConstraint.m:1558)
9   Foundation                      0x00000001862db9c4 -[NSLayoutConstraint _addToEngine:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 272 (NSLayoutConstraint.m:1597)
10  UIKit                           0x000000018f0411a4 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _layoutEngine_didAddLayoutConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 488 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:758)
11  UIKit                           0x000000018f0474cc -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _constraints_didChangeAutoresizingConstraintsArrayForContainedView:] +     348 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:1039)
12  UIKit                           0x000000018f0416e8 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _updateAutoresizingConstraints] + 176 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:1094)
13  UIKit                           0x000000018fa62e90 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateSystemConstraints] + 112 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:4294)
14  UIKit                           0x000000018fa619b8 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _sendUpdateConstraintsIfNecessaryForSecondPass:] + 188 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:0)
15  UIKit                           0x000000018fa61e80 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 1008 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:4097)
16  UIKit                           0x000000018fa61d58 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 712 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:4078)
17  Foundation                      0x00000001862db4dc -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 168 (NSISEngine.m:2158)
18  UIKit                           0x000000018fa62618 __100-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:]_block_invoke + 92 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:4143)
19  UIKit                           0x000000018fa61204 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withUnsatisfiableConstraintsLoggingSuspendedIfEngineDelegateExists:] + 116 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:3888)
20  UIKit                           0x000000018fa62234 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:] + 168 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:4142)
21  UIKit                           0x000000018fa63260 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsAtEngineLevelIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:] + 428 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:4398)
22  UIKit                           0x000000018ef6bd3c -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 892 (UIView.m:10310)
23  (Appname)                           0x0000000100d90f8c 0x100d1c000 + 479116
24  (Appname)                           0x0000000100dd3e28 0x100d1c000 + 753192
25  UIKit                           0x000000018f9e2844 -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:notify:] + 312 (UICollectionView.m:1979)
26  UIKit                           0x000000018efb906c -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 3864 (UICollectionView.m:2933)
27  UIKit                           0x000000018efb3d28 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 356 (UICollectionView.m:3534)
28  UIKit                           0x000000018ef56e18 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1276 (UIView.m:15124)
29  QuartzCore                      0x00000001899e3948 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 184 (CALayer.mm:9302)
30  QuartzCore                      0x00000001899e7ad0 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 332 (CALayer.mm:9182)
31  QuartzCore                      0x000000018995431c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 336 (CALayer.mm:2416)
32  QuartzCore                      0x000000018997bb40 CA::Transaction::commit() + 540 (CATransactionInternal.mm:425)
33  QuartzCore                      0x000000018997c980 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 92 (CATransactionInternal.mm:795)
34  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185946cdc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32 (CFRunLoop.c:1824)
35  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185944694 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 412 (CFRunLoop.c:1934)
36  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185944c50 __CFRunLoopRun + 1292 (CFRunLoop.c:2948)
37  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185864c58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3245)
38  GraphicsServices                0x0000000187710f84 GSEventRunModal + 100 (GSEvent.c:2245)
39  UIKit                           0x000000018efbd5c4 UIApplicationMain + 236 (UIApplication.m:3956)
40  (Appname)                           0x0000000100f30d3c 0x100d1c000 + 2182460
41  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018538456c start + 4
```

my app rejected from apple. I got crash log as you can see. Any help ?
thank

Comment: `0x8badf00d` basically means that your app was unresponsive for too long (10 seconds in this case) and it was killed by the watchdog.  From the stack trace it looks like it got stuck trying to layout your view.  What device did they test on (they would have told you in the rejection)?  Have you tested a TestFlight build on this device?